# XPath showing only 1 div container

Tags: php, xpath

For hours search i was needed to ask my first question.

I want output of all divs with the same name: `<div class="container timelineicon owners right">` on https://finnik.nl/kenteken/PV752X

My xpath: `$nodes3 = $finder->query('//div[@class="container timelineicon owners right"]');`

Output shows only the first entry:

```
06-10-2017

Nieuwe eigenaar type:
Voertuig is geregistreerd door een onbekende entiteit.
```

nodes3

```
//3

$tmp_dom3 = new DOMDocument(); 
foreach ($nodes3 as $node3) 
    {
    $tmp_dom3->appendChild($tmp_dom3->importNode($node3,true));
    }
  $innerHTML3.=trim($tmp_dom3->saveHTML()); 

  $buffdom3 = new DOMDocument();
  @$buffdom3->loadHTML($innerHTML3);
    # Iterate over all the <a> tags
    foreach($buffdom3->getElementsByTagName('div') as $link3) {
}
```

I hope some one can help me.

Comment: How you use `$nodes3`?

Comment: I added to the post

Answer (score 0):

for me

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('./data.html');
$finder = new DOMXPath($doc);
$nodes = $finder->query('//div[@class="container timelineicon owners right"]');

foreach ($nodes as $node)  {
    var_dump($node->textContent);
}
```

returne two nodes:

> 24-10-2017
> Nieuwe eigenaar type:
> Voertuig geregistreerd door particulier.

and

> 06-10-2017
> Nieuwe eigenaar type:
> Voertuig is geregistreerd door een onbekende entiteit.

Comment: Thank you very much! I just try it and have the same results as you!

It's looks like it's some problem from the node to json_encode.